# how to use the cardboard sdk for pc vr game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

so I want to create a vr game using unity3d and cardboard sdk for PC(windows), which I'll stream to my phone screen using kinoConsol. I created a simple scene when I build it for android,it works fine , I mean it shows the dual sbs camera(screen), but a windows build shows only one normal camera(screen).. is there a way I can use the cardboard sdk to show the sbs camera(screen) in a windows build ?? if not is there any thing else available to achieve this ?

Comment: I will stream it on my mobile phone screen using kinoConsol

Comment: It is a bad idea. The streaming lag will cause nausea. Also, you obviously cant use the cardboard sdk on a PC build. If you really want to stream, use Trinus VR instead.

Answer (score 2):

Side by side is easy, just place two cameras where the eyes should be and change their viewport rect to half width. Now you have a side by side stereo renderer without any external library. Cardboard also adds some distortion to the lenses, but it is not that important to use it in your case.

Your second, and much bigger problem is the gyroscope - you have to somehow communicate the position of your headset to your unity app on your pc. This is not trivial and probably will require finding or building an persistent service on your android device that will send the orientation data to your desktop app.